# Create a File if it is not already there

Tags: java, file, io

In Java we can create a reference to a file by...

```
File counterFile = new File("countervalue.txt");
```

but how do we create the file if it does not already exist?

Comment: `if (!f.exists()) f.createNewFile();`

Answer (score 2):

The basic way to create the file would be calling the [`File#createNewFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29) method:

```
File counterFile = new File("countervalue.txt");
try {
    counterFile.createNewFile();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("File couldn't been created.");
}
```

Now, if you want to create a new File and fill it with data, you can use a `FileWriter` and a `PrintWriter` for text files (assuming this for the `txt` extension in your sample):

```
File counterFile = new File("countervalue.txt");
PrintWriter pw = null;
try {
    //it will automatically create the file
    pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(counterFile));
    pw.println("Hello world!");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("File couldn't been created.");
} finally {
    if (pw != null) {
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

If you want to just append data to your file, use the [`FileWriter(File, boolean)`](http://goo.gl/OTNbJ) constructor passing `true` as the second parameter:

```
pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(counterFile, true));
```

Answer (score 1):

Easily done in java

```
File counterFile = new File("countervalue.txt");
counterFile.createNewFile();
```